# pip install failing with: OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied on directory

Tags: python, permissions, pip, installation

`pip install -r requirements.txt` fails with the exception below `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/...`. What's wrong and how do I fix this? (I am trying to setup [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com))

```
Installing collected packages: amqp, anyjson, arrow, beautifulsoup4, billiard, boto, braintree, celery, cffi, cryptography, Django, django-bower, django-braces, django-celery, django-crispy-forms, django-debug-toolbar, django-disqus, django-embed-video, django-filter, django-merchant, django-pagination, django-payments, django-storages, django-vote, django-wysiwyg-redactor, easy-thumbnails, enum34, gnureadline, idna, ipaddress, ipython, kombu, mock, names, ndg-httpsclient, Pillow, pyasn1, pycparser, pycrypto, PyJWT, pyOpenSSL, python-dateutil, pytz, requests, six, sqlparse, stripe, suds-jurko
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1436, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 672, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 902, in move_wheel_files
    pycompile=self.pycompile,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 206, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 193, in clobber
    os.makedirs(destsubdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp-1.4.6.dist-info'
```

Comment: Related (macOS/homebrew specific) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004708/osx-el-capitan-sudo-pip-install-oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted

Answer (score 100, accepted):

## Option a) Create a virtualenv, activate it and install:

```
virtualenv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

## Option b) Install in your homedir:

```
pip install --user -r requirements.txt
```

My recommendation use safe (a) option, so that requirements of this project do not interfere with other projects requirements.

Comment: I got an error like this `sudo:pip: command not found` on my aws ec2 instance when running this command. Please help.

Comment: @user3768495 Likely your version of `pip` is in `/usr/local/bin` which is not on root user's `PATH`. You can try providing the absolute path `/usr/local/bin/pip` in the command above.

Comment: @user3768495  Probably, pip is not installed by default. Which distro is your EC2? Also, python2 might not be installed, so either you install python2 or use pip3. Be careful with this though.

Comment: I've read this is not recommended in multiple places now. Seems like we should caution against sudo usage when running pip (see Bert's answer)

Comment: @JustusEapen: I don't know how I feel about that. I don't think the proper answer to OP's question is a manual on basic computer hygiene, including "don't run shady code with superuser permissions" and "brush your teeth regularly". I find the optimal answer should point out that packages can be installed on a per-user or system-wide basis, and that installing system-wide, as OP wished (there are perfectly cromulent reasons to do so) requires super user permission. Cautioning against installing packages on the system path is probably some else's job on some other SO question.

Comment: I think @bert's answer to use `--user` argument is more appropriate than `sudo` unless you actually need to install it globally for all users

Comment: downvoting because of `sudo` advise. even though it works now, it is going to give you a lot of headaches in the future.

Comment: `sudo` will not always work, and is more like using a cheat code. Should mention `--user` and explain more about use of each.

Comment: `pip install --user` worked out for me..I personally don't like encouraging the use of `sudo` unnecessarily

Comment: @Gerald will it? It depends entirely on whether OP wants to install Django on the systemwise python path or on a per-user basis, doesn't it? It's blatantly obvious to *anybody* that installing *anything* from a repository on the system path requires a certain amount of trust. I don't see the need to downvote. It's not the answerer's duty to give OP the "basic security 101" lecture, since OP likely knows it perfectly well. If anything, it's OP duty to be more specific. @DanCiborowski: I don't see how `sudo` is a "cheat code". You *need* to achieve su privileges somehow to alter the system.

Comment: I am getting the error on the virtual env: has anyone?

Answer (score 356):

Rather than using `sudo` with `pip install`, It's better to first try `pip install --user`. If this fails then take a look at the top post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004708/osx-el-capitan-sudo-pip-install-oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted).

The reason you shouldn't use `sudo` is as follows:

When you run pip with `sudo`, you are running arbitrary Python code from the Internet as a root user, which is quite a big security risk. If someone puts up a malicious project on PyPI and you install it, you give an attacker root access to your machine.

Comment: Good observation. That, after all, goes for all `sudo x install`, for all `x` (including `x = make`).

Comment: You answer really helped me. I have no write access to the specific directory and cannot use `sudo`. The only working method is yours. Thanks!

Comment: This also solved my problem. What does adding --user do?

Comment: @MilesJohnson Adding `--user` installs the package in your home directory, rather than the root. Installing something to this location doesn't require any extra privileges.

Comment: This! This! 1000 times this! Not only is this a safer approach to pip in general it is a solution to many of the errors found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3452888) about upgrading packages.

Comment: Additionally, if you are on a remote server behind a proxy, "sudo" prevents you from fetching the packages from internet repositories and/or git repositories of the remote server's network.

Comment: All mention of `sudo` was removed a year ago. This answer is obsolete - please revise and update it. You also need to mention per-user vs system-wide installs, and permissions. Don't use your answer to directly criticize other answers, that will tend to obsolete quickly.

Comment: @smci My answer does more than just “directly criticise” the accepted answer. It explains exactly why you should not use sudo and such an explanation is still valid even if the original answer has been edited. Furthermore, on top of explaining what you should not do, it also explains what you *should* do and so it still makes sense without that context.

Answer (score 30):

You are trying to install a package on the system-wide path without having the permission to do so.

1. <s>In general, you can use `sudo` to temporarily obtain **superuser**
   permissions **at your responsibility** in order to install the package on the system-wide path:</s>

   ```
    sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
   ```

   Find more about `sudo` [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo).

   Actually, this is a bad idea and there's no good use case for it, see @wim's comment.
2. If you don't want to make system-wide changes, you can install the package on your **per-user** path using the `--user` flag.

   All it takes is:

   ```
    pip install --user runloop requirements.txt
   ```
3. Finally, for **even finer grained control**, you can also use a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/), which might be the superior solution for a development environment, especially if you are working on **multiple projects** and want to keep track of each one's dependencies.

   After activating your virtualenv with

   `$ my-virtualenv/bin/activate`

   the following command will install the package inside the virtualenv (and *not* on the system-wide path):

   `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Running pip with root comes with [security risks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42021993/3202958)

Comment: Running *anything that runs code from the Internet* as root comes with security risks.

Comment: This is nearly the best answer, but still needs updating. a) Now we have `pyenv/pipenv`, should mention those, in preference to `virtualenv` (or `conda-env`) b)  sudo considered harmful, and see the other answers why. So put the env-based answer first, and the sudo one last, with a big disclaimer.

Comment: You did a good job editing, can you just move 1) `sudo pip install` to the bottom, as it's now the least desirable approach, is a security hole, and is generally unnecessary.

Comment: `sudo pip install -r requirements.txt` is never right. **The system's python environment belongs to the system, period**. If you do install more python stuff into the system, do it with package manager only (e.g. `sudo yum install`, `apt-get`, etc...) since those repos should have safe and compatible versions of libraries avail.

Comment: I completely fail to see why there would not be a legitimate case to install something system-wide through a channel other than `yum`/`apt-get`, but we'll agree to disagree here.
By that line of reasoning, there isn't a case for installing something by hand either - i.e. the old `sudo make install`?

Comment: @TobiaTesan The old `sudo make install`, usually compiled + linked code, is not really analogous with a `sudo pip install` since *installing to the system Python env can invalidate dependencies*. Suppose there is a system service `python-frobnicator`, which has a dependency on `froblib` (this will also be in the package manager and pinned to a compatible version), and then you `sudo pip install` some other app or lib that has a dependency on "`froblib > 1.2`".  Pip will happily "upgrade" the system version of `froblib` with a newer one, which may be incompatible/untested and break the system.

Comment: Note there can only be one version installed per-env, this is why Python has [virtualenv](https://hynek.me/articles/virtualenv-lives/).

Comment: @wim I see what you mean now, and seems to me like a good point to make. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Just clarifying what worked for me after much pain in linux (ubuntu based) on permission denied errors, and leveraging from Bert's answer above, I now use ...

```
$ pip install --user <package-name>
```

or if running pip on a requirements file ...

```
$ pip install --user -r requirements.txt
```

and these work reliably for every pip install including creating virtual environments.

However, the cleanest solution *in my further experience* has been to install `python-virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` with `sudo apt-get install` at the system level.

Then, inside virtual environments, use `pip install` without the `--user` flag *AND* without `sudo`. Much cleaner, safer, and easier overall.

Comment: I get a "Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv." error when trying to use `pip install --user -r requirements.txt`

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani the answer has been edited since your question. It now says 
« inside virtual environments, use pip install without the --user flag AND without sudo »

Answer (score 14):

User doesn't have write permission for some Python installation paths. You can give the permission by:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /absolute/path/to/directory
```

So you should give permission, then try to install it again, if you have new paths you should also give permission:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/python2.7/
```

Comment: For python installed with brew, this is the right answer because brew maintains packages as the local user (no root).

Comment: chowning the /usr/local dir is not a good idea. It does not belong to the user. You should read about unix file structure.

Comment: Stuff under [`/usr`](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/usr.html) would typically be owned by root, these days. Recursively chowning there could majorly screw up your system. **AVOID**.

Answer (score 1):

If you need permissions, you cannot use 'pip' with 'sudo'.
You can do a trick, so that you can use 'sudo' and install package. Just place 'sudo python -m ...' in front of your pip command.

```
sudo python -m pip install --user -r package_name
```

Comment: Seems fine to me, but could you please add some explanation.

Comment: Try --user before going the sudo route

Answer (score 0):

It was worked for me by below commands

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org PACKAGE_NAME --user
```

or

```
pip install --user <package name>
```

Example:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org matplotlib --user
```

Answer (score -1):

So, I got this same exact error for a completely different reason. Due to a totally separate, but known [Homebrew + pip bug](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Homebrew-and-Python.md#Note-on-pip-install---user), I had followed [this workaround](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#vendoring) listed on Google Cloud's help docs, where you create a .pydistutils.cfg file in your home directory. This file has special config that you're only supposed to use for your install of certain libraries. I should have removed that disutils.cfg file after installing the packages, but I forgot to do so. So the fix for me was actually just...

`rm ~/.pydistutils.cfg`.

And then everything worked as normal. Of course, if you have some config in that file for a real reason, then you won't want to just straight rm that file. But in case anyone else did that workaround, and forgot to remove that file, this did the trick for me!

Answer (score -5):

It is due permission problem,

```
sudo chown -R $USER /path to your python installed directory
```

## default it would be `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/`

or try,

```
pip install --user -r package_name
```

and then say, `pip install -r requirements.txt` this will install inside your env

dont say, `sudo pip install -r requirements.txt` this is will install into arbitrary python path.

Comment: As already noted in another older answer with the same advice, don't `chown` system files to belong to regular users. This is just the `sudo pip install` problem in spades. If you have to do one of those, `sudo pip install` is way better.