# Why does pip give a permission denied error when installing scikit-learn?

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, pip

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 freshly installed, and I have installed pip but when I try to install scikit I get the following error message:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn'
```

Comment: Please always google the error message first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied

Answer (score 1):

`$ pip install --user sklearn`.

Or use a virtualenv. Do *not* use `sudo pip` which the other question recommends.

Comment: The posted question is very valid. Installing sklearn with pip fails inside a virtualenv!

Comment: No, same error... sklearn tries to install things under the system dir eventhough pip is running inside virtualenv... not sure who the culprit is, maybe my virtualenv install is corrupted... I managed to make it work by editing pip code and forcing platlib=purelib