# Permission denied when calling library function

Tags: python, python-3.x, shap

I am attempting to run a tutorial https://slundberg.github.io/shap/notebooks/Census%20income%20classification%20with%20XGBoost.html

where I'm stuck at

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import xgboost
import shap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

shap.initjs()

X,y = shap.datasets.adult()
```

which gives the errors:

```
con@V:~/Scripts/python3$ python3 0.shap.py 
2021-03-25 15:58:04.143075: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-03-25 15:58:04.143191: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "0.shap.py", line 9, in <module>
    X,y = shap.datasets.adult()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/shap/datasets.py", line 112, in adult
    cache(github_data_url + "adult.data"),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/shap/datasets.py", line 249, in cache
    os.mkdir(data_dir)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/shap/cached_data'
```

I'm assuming that `Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` isn't relevant, because I'm just running a VM, not a GPU.

But the confusing part is `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/shap/cached_data` doesn't even exist.

Installing `virtualenv` did not fix the problem - same error.

While similar errors are on ["PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages'" installing Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39950254/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-usr-lib-python3-5-site-package) I'm not getting the error from installing anything

How can I run `X,y = shap.datasets.adult()` without these permission errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that a `cache` function tried to make a directory in `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/shap/` which requires `sudo` permission.

The solution is to run `sudo`, I think only once for each dataset.

Or have installed a personal version of `shap`