# pip3 install --force-reinstall -r requirements.txt error in Amazon EC2

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pip, python-3.6

Try to install requirements.txt in Amazon EC2

```
pip3 install --force-reinstall -r requirements.txt
```

But get the following error messages

```
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.

To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable

Processing /opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/fdab5f8f-d9cf-4e28-48c7-38c4ee85b3c3/volume/cffi_1606255125152/work
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/fdab5f8f-d9cf-4e28-48c7-38c4ee85b3c3/volume/cffi_1606255125152/work'
```

I saw this post [error when "sudo pip" on an AWS ec2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697310/error-when-sudo-pip-on-an-aws-ec2-instance)

here are some PATH variables

```
    echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin

sudo grep secure_path /etc/sudoers
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

so I tried

```
sudo grep secure_path /etc/sudoers

sudo env "PATH=$PATH" pip3 install --force-reinstall -r requirements.txt
```

But get the following error messages instead

```
WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `pip3 install --user` instead.

Invalid requirement: 'cffi @ file:///opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/fdab5f8f-d9cf-4e28-48c7-

38c4ee85b3c3/volume/cffi_1606255125152/work'

It looks like a path. Does it exist ?
```

Could anyone help? thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `python -m pip install --force-reinstall -r requirements.txt`?

Comment: Hi @WillWalsh thank you. I just tried ```python3 -m pip install --force-reinstall -r requirements.txt``` and got a similar error message

```Processing /opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/fdab5f8f-d9cf-4e28-48c7-38c4ee85b3c3/volume/cffi_1606255125152/work
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/fdab5f8f-d9cf-4e28-48c7-38c4ee85b3c3/volume/cffi_1606255125152/work'```

Comment: got it. there are some weird lines in my requirement.txt from CONDA. just fixed it and the install is successful now. thank you!