# pip upgrade OSError: [Errno:13] Permission Denied

Tags: python, ubuntu, operating-system, pip

I need to upgrade pip on my Ubuntu system but I am getting error:

```
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 8.1.2
    Uninstalling pip-8.1.2:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-8.1.2
  Rolling back uninstall of pip
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shivams334/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/shivams334/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/shivams334/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 742, in install
**kwargs
  File "/home/shivams334/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 831, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/home/shivams334/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/home/shivams334/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 346, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/home/shivams334/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 317, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/home/shivams334/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1.dist-info'
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Maybe I should go with 'chown' but don't know how to use it. Please help.

Comment: Which command did you run? Did you use sudo?

Comment: @Biffen thanks for your reply. No, I used 'pip install --upgrade pip'

Comment: He tries `pip install -U pip`…

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install -r: OSError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to upgrade your system-wide Python, you need to run this command with administrator privilege:

```
sudo pip install -U pip
```

But, I recommend you not changing/polluting your system-wide Python. Instead use a virtualenv:

```
virtualenv myapp
source myapp/bin/activate
pip install -U pip  # <- only if virtualenv is not up to date
```