# I get an error when I try to install BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

What is wrong?

[here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kRPv.png)

Comment: use `sudo pip3 install BeautifulSoup4`

Comment: @akashkarothiya the answer is right.

Comment: No it isn't. Stop advising the use of `sudo`! [See here for why and what to do instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied/42021993#42021993)

Answer (score 1):

Run the install command with elevated privileges.

`sudo pip install bs4`

Comment: Stop advising the use of `sudo` for `pip install`. It's dangerous and irresponsible. [See here for why and what to do instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied/42021993#42021993)