# Can't install packages in PyCharm (OSError: [Errno 13])

Tags: python, pycharm

I can't install packages in PyCharm

throws this error

```
Collecting oktaauth
  Downloading oktaauth-0.2-py2-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.8 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from oktaauth)
Collecting argparse (from oktaauth)
  Downloading argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting beautifulsoup4>=4.4 (from oktaauth)
  Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py2-none-any.whl (86kB)
Installing collected packages: argparse, beautifulsoup4, oktaauth

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 247, in move_wheel_files
    prefix=prefix,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/locations.py", line 153, in distutils_scheme
    i.finalize_options()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 346, in finalize_options
    self.create_home_path()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 565, in create_home_path
    os.makedirs(path, 0700)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/karanj/Library/Python/2.7'
```

I found soltutions by asking me to try installing it by being root or trying sudo with the command and try installing the package. But I don't want to install the package by appending sudo to it.

Any solutions?

Comment: which command are you using to install the packages ?

Comment: If it says permision denied, you should use sudo although you don't want.

Comment: what the permissions of `/Users/karanj/Library` ? Can you add output of `ls -l` it will show owner and group of the files

Comment: Reference for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied

Answer (score 2):

When you start a python project, always use [Python virtual environemnt](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). Avoid using use `sudo pip install`.

You can either

1. [create Pycharm virtual environment](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html), or
2. Create your typical virtualenv, then [add external virtualenv](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/adding-existing-virtual-environment.html)  to Pycharm, or
3. Use [pycharm with conda](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-environment.html), another virtual environment.

Comment: create virtual environment with conda in pycharm works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try with `sudo`
If there is a requirement file e.g. `sudo pip install -r requirements.txt`
Or for standalone package

```
sudo pip install <package-name>
```

Comment: I can install packages in the terminal by appending sudo but PyCharm doesn't append sudo. So every time i have to install a package I have to go to the command line and install the package.