# Trying to install Pandas for Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, error-handling

I can't seem to install Pandas for Python on my Macbook. I have gone through different threads to try to understand but have not been able to find a solution.

i have used `pip install pandas`

The Error i get:

```
xxx-MacBook-Pro:~ edss$ pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-0.22.0-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from pandas)
Collecting numpy>=1.9.0 (from pandas)
  Using cached numpy-1.14.2-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from pandas)
Installing collected packages: numpy, pandas
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.8.0rc1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling numpy-1.8.0rc1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/km/5sv3zt816sl74rb9qcmt0vr40000gn/T/pip-LvWuDt-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

UPDATE -----!!

- I found that I could just download Anaconda and use Spyder.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: You need to run it as root user (`sudo pip install pandas`) or as a safer way you can install it on a virtual-environment.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with the answers saying to use `sudo pip install` to get around permissions errors.  This is not always a safe approach.  On OSX, you should be able to get around your current error using the `--user` flag.

So:

`pip install --user pandas`

However, as @Kasramvd has noted in the comments, one of the safest options is to use a virtual environment.

Not saying that using `sudo` is bad, just that you should understand what you are doing when you use it.

From [What are the risks of running 'sudo pip'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055859/what-are-the-risks-of-running-sudo-pip?answertab=active#tab-top):

> When you run pip with sudo, you run setup.py with sudo. In other words, you run arbitrary Python code from the Internet as root. If someone puts up a malicious project on PyPI and you install it, you give an attacker root access to your machine. Prior to some recent fixes to pip and PyPI, an attacker could also run a man in the middle attack to inject their code when you download a trustworthy project.

(That answer may be somewhat dated, but the first part holds true)

Answer (score 0):

try to run wih `sudo`
if you want to know why you get this problem [check this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47254754/oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted)

Answer (score -1):

Pip is highly unreliable.  Try download the source and compiling it.  That almost always works.

As suggested above.  Try it with Sudo first.  It looks like that is blocking your pip install attempt.