# I can't install package with pip on MacOS 10.13.4

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pip

Here is my pip version

pip --version
pip 10.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)

When I tried to install package like scapy in pip, here is the error:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/f8/988xffkd71v49lrmlxgl8r400000gn/T/pip-install-3mdpz8/scapy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/f8/988xffkd71v49lrmlxgl8r400000gn/T/pip-record-_qsfbp/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/f8/988xffkd71v49lrmlxgl8r400000gn/T/pip-install-3mdpz8/scapy/
```

And then I tried "sudo pip install setuptools --upgrade", and here is the error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', '/private/var/folders/f8/988xffkd71v49lrmlxgl8r400000gn/T/pip-uninstall-ROqyV3/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/f8/988xffkd71v49lrmlxgl8r400000gn/T/pip-uninstall-ROqyV3/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', '/private/var/folders/f8/988xffkd71v49lrmlxgl8r400000gn/T/pip-uninstall-ROqyV3/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/f8/988xffkd71v49lrmlxgl8r400000gn/T/pip-uninstall-ROqyV3/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', '/private/var/folders/f8/988xffkd71v49lrmlxgl8r400000gn/T/pip-uninstall-ROqyV3/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/f8/988xffkd71v49lrmlxgl8r400000gn/T/pip-uninstall-ROqyV3/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', '/private/var/folders/f8/988xffkd71v49lrmlxgl8r400000gn/T/pip-uninstall-ROqyV3/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/f8/988xffkd71v49lrmlxgl8r400000gn/T/pip-uninstall-ROqyV3/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', '/private/var/folders/f8/988xffkd71v49lrmlxgl8r400000gn/T/pip-uninstall-ROqyV3/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/f8/988xffkd71v49lrmlxgl8r400000gn/T/pip-uninstall-ROqyV3/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib'")]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OSX El Capitan: sudo pip install OSError: \[Errno: 1\] Operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004708/osx-el-capitan-sudo-pip-install-oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted)

Comment: sudo pip install setuptools --upgrade.  try pip install --upgrade setuptools.

Comment: Are you running python2 or python3?  If python3, how did you install it?

Comment: Try to run pip with the '--user' flag as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47254754/oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--user` flag.

If you have installed python3 use `pip3` instead of `pip`