# Downloading python module (VPython) on macbook

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pip, vpython

I am trying to download the VPython module onto my macbook using pip. But I keep getting this error on the terminal.
[image: Terminal error]

Comment: `sudo pip3 install vpython`?

Comment: Or `sudo pip2 install vpython` for Python  2.7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install -r: OSError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied)

Answer (score 0):

Before the red text, there is an error which states

> error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/vpnotebook': Permission denied

Try do run the same command with superuser; `sudo pip install <package>`

Comment: What about `pip install --user <package>`?

Comment: I tried Sudo pip install vpython but when I try import vpython on python shell, it says there is no module with that name