# Superset installation fails

Tags: python, apache-superset

I am trying to install superset on ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64 in a virtual box, but I keep getting the following error. I am both new on ubuntu (linux) and superset. Any ideas how to fix this? please. I added an image that gives the error in red in the terminal, and details of the installation. thanks.

```
max@ubuntu:~$ pip install superset
Collecting superset
  Downloading superset-0.22.1.tar.gz (58.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 58.3MB 19kB/s 
Collecting boto3>=1.4.6 (from superset)
  Downloading boto3-1.5.27-py2.py3-none-any.whl (128kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 926kB/s 
Collecting celery==4.1.0 (from superset)
  Downloading celery-4.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (400kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 409kB 895kB/s 
Collecting colorama==0.3.9 (from superset)
  Downloading colorama-0.3.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cryptography==1.9 (from superset)
  Downloading cryptography-1.9.tar.gz (409kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 419kB 970kB/s 
Collecting flask==0.12.2 (from superset)
  Downloading Flask-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (83kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 1.3MB/s 
Collecting flask-appbuilder==1.9.4 (from superset)
  Downloading Flask-AppBuilder-1.9.4.tar.gz (1.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.5MB 676kB/s 
Collecting flask-cache==0.13.1 (from superset)
  Downloading Flask-Cache-0.13.1.tar.gz (45kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 1.7MB/s 
Collecting flask-migrate==2.0.3 (from superset)
  Downloading Flask-Migrate-2.0.3.tar.gz
Collecting flask-script==2.0.5 (from superset)
  Downloading Flask-Script-2.0.5.tar.gz (42kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 1.0MB/s 
Collecting flask-sqlalchemy==2.1 (from superset)
  Downloading Flask-SQLAlchemy-2.1.tar.gz (95kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 102kB 1.1MB/s 
Collecting flask-testing==0.6.2 (from superset)
  Downloading Flask-Testing-0.6.2.tar.gz (129kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 1.1MB/s 
Collecting flask-wtf==0.14.2 (from superset)
  Downloading Flask_WTF-0.14.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting flower==0.9.1 (from superset)
  Downloading flower-0.9.1.tar.gz (3.9MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.9MB 277kB/s 
Collecting future<0.17,>=0.16.0 (from superset)
  Downloading future-0.16.0.tar.gz (824kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 829kB 744kB/s 
Collecting humanize==0.5.1 (from superset)
  Downloading humanize-0.5.1.tar.gz
Collecting gunicorn==19.7.1 (from superset)
  Downloading gunicorn-19.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (111kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 969kB/s 
Collecting idna==2.5 (from superset)
  Downloading idna-2.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (55kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 1.1MB/s 
Collecting markdown==2.6.8 (from superset)
  Downloading Markdown-2.6.8.tar.gz (307kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 317kB 4.3MB/s 
Collecting pandas==0.20.3 (from superset)
  Downloading pandas-0.20.3-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (22.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 22.4MB 70kB/s 
Collecting parsedatetime==2.0.0 (from superset)
  Downloading parsedatetime-2.0-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting pathlib2==2.3.0 (from superset)
  Downloading pathlib2-2.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pydruid==0.3.1 (from superset)
  Downloading pydruid-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting PyHive>=0.4.0 (from superset)
  Downloading PyHive-0.5.0.tar.gz (40kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 40kB 1.1MB/s 
Collecting python-dateutil==2.6.0 (from superset)
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (194kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 194kB 1.2MB/s 
Collecting pyyaml>=3.11 (from superset)
  Downloading PyYAML-3.12.tar.gz (253kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 256kB 1.1MB/s 
Collecting requests==2.17.3 (from superset)
  Downloading requests-2.17.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (87kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 1.3MB/s 
Collecting simplejson==3.10.0 (from superset)
  Downloading simplejson-3.10.0.tar.gz (77kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 1.6MB/s 
Collecting six==1.10.0 (from superset)
  Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting sqlalchemy==1.1.9 (from superset)
  Downloading SQLAlchemy-1.1.9.tar.gz (5.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 5.2MB 267kB/s 
Collecting sqlalchemy-utils==0.32.16 (from superset)
  Downloading SQLAlchemy-Utils-0.32.16.tar.gz (120kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 122kB 1.2MB/s 
Collecting sqlparse==0.2.3 (from superset)
  Downloading sqlparse-0.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting thrift>=0.9.3 (from superset)
  Downloading thrift-0.11.0.tar.gz (52kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 1.3MB/s 
Collecting thrift-sasl>=0.2.1 (from superset)
  Downloading thrift_sasl-0.3.0.tar.gz
Collecting unidecode>=0.04.21 (from superset)
  Downloading Unidecode-1.0.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl (235kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 235kB 1.3MB/s 
Collecting botocore<1.9.0,>=1.8.41 (from boto3>=1.4.6->superset)
  Downloading botocore-1.8.41-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.1MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 4.1MB 316kB/s 
Collecting s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.10 (from boto3>=1.4.6->superset)
  Downloading s3transfer-0.1.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (59kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 989kB/s 
Collecting jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 (from boto3>=1.4.6->superset)
  Downloading jmespath-0.9.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting kombu<5.0,>=4.0.2 (from celery==4.1.0->superset)
  Downloading kombu-4.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (181kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 184kB 1.2MB/s 
Collecting pytz>dev (from celery==4.1.0->superset)
  Downloading pytz-2018.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (509kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 512kB 1.1MB/s 
Collecting billiard<3.6.0,>=3.5.0.2 (from celery==4.1.0->superset)
  Downloading billiard-3.5.0.3.tar.gz (149kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 153kB 1.3MB/s 
Collecting asn1crypto>=0.21.0 (from cryptography==1.9->superset)
  Downloading asn1crypto-0.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (101kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 102kB 1.1MB/s 
Collecting enum34 (from cryptography==1.9->superset)
  Downloading enum34-1.1.6-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting ipaddress (from cryptography==1.9->superset)
  Downloading ipaddress-1.0.19.tar.gz
Collecting cffi>=1.7 (from cryptography==1.9->superset)
  Downloading cffi-1.11.4-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (406kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 409kB 991kB/s 
Collecting Jinja2>=2.4 (from flask==0.12.2->superset)
  Downloading Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (126kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 1.1MB/s 
Collecting Werkzeug>=0.7 (from flask==0.12.2->superset)
  Downloading Werkzeug-0.14.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (322kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 327kB 862kB/s 
Collecting click>=2.0 (from flask==0.12.2->superset)
  Downloading click-6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (71kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 1.1MB/s 
Collecting itsdangerous>=0.21 (from flask==0.12.2->superset)
  Downloading itsdangerous-0.24.tar.gz (46kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 1.0MB/s 
Collecting Flask-Babel==0.11.1 (from flask-appbuilder==1.9.4->superset)
  Downloading Flask-Babel-0.11.1.tar.gz (40kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 40kB 1.4MB/s 
Collecting Flask-Login==0.2.11 (from flask-appbuilder==1.9.4->superset)
  Downloading Flask-Login-0.2.11.tar.gz
Collecting Flask-OpenID==1.2.5 (from flask-appbuilder==1.9.4->superset)
  Downloading Flask-OpenID-1.2.5.tar.gz (43kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 1.5MB/s 
Collecting alembic>=0.6 (from flask-migrate==2.0.3->superset)
  Downloading alembic-0.9.7.tar.gz (1.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.0MB 645kB/s 
Collecting WTForms (from flask-wtf==0.14.2->superset)
  Downloading WTForms-2.1.zip (553kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 563kB 990kB/s 
Collecting tornado==4.2.0 (from flower==0.9.1->superset)
  Downloading tornado-4.2.tar.gz (433kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 440kB 1.6MB/s 
Collecting babel>=1.0 (from flower==0.9.1->superset)
  Downloading Babel-2.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.8MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 6.8MB 197kB/s 
Collecting futures (from flower==0.9.1->superset)
  Downloading futures-3.2.0-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy>=1.7.0 (from pandas==0.20.3->superset)
  Downloading numpy-1.14.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (16.9MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 16.9MB 95kB/s 
Collecting scandir; python_version < "3.5" (from pathlib2==2.3.0->superset)
  Downloading scandir-1.7.tar.gz
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests==2.17.3->superset)
  Downloading certifi-2018.1.18-py2.py3-none-any.whl (151kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 153kB 1.2MB/s 
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests==2.17.3->superset)
  Downloading chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 143kB 1.1MB/s 
Collecting urllib3<1.22,>=1.21.1 (from requests==2.17.3->superset)
  Downloading urllib3-1.21.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (131kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 1.0MB/s 
Collecting sasl>=0.2.1 (from thrift-sasl>=0.2.1->superset)
  Downloading sasl-0.2.1.tar.gz
Collecting docutils>=0.10 (from botocore<1.9.0,>=1.8.41->boto3>=1.4.6->superset)
  Downloading docutils-0.14-py2-none-any.whl (543kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 552kB 945kB/s 
Collecting amqp<3.0,>=2.1.4 (from kombu<5.0,>=4.0.2->celery==4.1.0->superset)
  Downloading amqp-2.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (48kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 1.8MB/s 
Collecting pycparser (from cffi>=1.7->cryptography==1.9->superset)
  Downloading pycparser-2.18.tar.gz (245kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 256kB 1.1MB/s 
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2>=2.4->flask==0.12.2->superset)
  Downloading MarkupSafe-1.0.tar.gz
Collecting python-openid>=2.0 (from Flask-OpenID==1.2.5->flask-appbuilder==1.9.4->superset)
  Downloading python-openid-2.2.5.tar.gz (301kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 307kB 937kB/s 
Collecting Mako (from alembic>=0.6->flask-migrate==2.0.3->superset)
  Downloading Mako-1.0.7.tar.gz (564kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 573kB 896kB/s 
Collecting python-editor>=0.3 (from alembic>=0.6->flask-migrate==2.0.3->superset)
  Downloading python-editor-1.0.3.tar.gz
Collecting backports.ssl_match_hostname (from tornado==4.2.0->flower==0.9.1->superset)
  Downloading backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.5.0.1.tar.gz
Collecting vine>=1.1.3 (from amqp<3.0,>=2.1.4->kombu<5.0,>=4.0.2->celery==4.1.0->superset)
  Downloading vine-1.1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: superset, cryptography, flask-appbuilder, flask-cache, flask-migrate, flask-script, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-testing, flower, future, humanize, markdown, PyHive, pyyaml, simplejson, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-utils, thrift, thrift-sasl, billiard, ipaddress, itsdangerous, Flask-Babel, Flask-Login, Flask-OpenID, alembic, WTForms, tornado, scandir, sasl, pycparser, MarkupSafe, python-openid, Mako, python-editor, backports.ssl-match-hostname
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for superset ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/17/53/df/9bc791dd9cd4fae01688d5d134daa6a50def2b7bfd9e2275ea
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cryptography ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/ff/a5/ef/186bb4f6a89ef0bb8373bf53e5c9884b96722f0857bd3111b8
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for flask-appbuilder ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/76/fa/88/d23864a02913bc4ad1c60ba9054d16e8020f5c6e79c77d753d
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for flask-cache ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/d3/ea/07/db4bcd93163f4ac63974a7ce7aa15df9d45cdc9864c8232f9c
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for flask-migrate ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/4f/1a/cd/241202c77554d1500b47f169a59432c33834f941e90769bf0e
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for flask-script ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/e2/ea/d8/8d114e46cef819f7d9879504a7f9cb2a88a479af2858223d9f
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for flask-sqlalchemy ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/cf/9f/1b/390c152e645c6e300fda9ed9c678c6e22717a3020fd02acb4d
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for flask-testing ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/10/34/47/2378abdc5f5ce79b1d9b26be4a1f14d485f0376e5dc6512822
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for flower ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/a3/0a/36/7c3642bbba1ded7a79c64c5bdc2a0958b88b73c84d60550b26
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for future ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/c2/50/7c/0d83b4baac4f63ff7a765bd16390d2ab43c93587fac9d6017a
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for humanize ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/d4/80/38/cfbfd95752f71f3812505b948b43383ddc99eedf835fc13b09
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for markdown ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/85/a7/08/33ee5cd488d0365d8bed79d1d4e5c28dd3fbfc7f6d0ad4bb09
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for PyHive ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/e7/59/27/943bcc03c98a37876394bc9f902bc9056f00166a9746555311
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyyaml ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/2c/f7/79/13f3a12cd723892437c0cfbde1230ab4d82947ff7b3839a4fc
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for simplejson ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/43/c5/ef/edcebbb19becffd2ba75bf219afdbb4ca85198b2d909f1b31b
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for sqlalchemy ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/62/c3/8f/12a643439a7ba36143e21533ac633b99da8537b1deb8d0f0c3
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for sqlalchemy-utils ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/f0/05/32/bf092b262dcb4f4a9eb87e93c1b88c63fb6e345ef88534d65d
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for thrift ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/7c/89/70/14df5740427cacf181649caeac8b673bbaba4698b28bf0bd12
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for thrift-sasl ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/c1/d3/ff/61b8321fd5fb3ec9aebee95e063cd53a48cf880db3513c35f0
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for billiard ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/85/15/e4/11683b23ab74c2a835845811976e664ab33df7d23c3cb23500
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for ipaddress ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/d7/6b/69/666188e8101897abb2e115d408d139a372bdf6bfa7abb5aef5
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for itsdangerous ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/fc/a8/66/24d655233c757e178d45dea2de22a04c6d92766abfb741129a
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Flask-Babel ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/99/65/6c/927249178edfdc24c9cb2d9fcea27f598a73b323a1b5e3a8fc
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Flask-Login ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/4b/58/2e/fbba562e845fb419f6157a504055275a4d1783a22ebe3124e8
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Flask-OpenID ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/3b/36/b4/ab2c592ee3b385f9db7fbcdeacdf766bca3dd4b5270d40690e
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for alembic ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/70/52/76/48b43681474e215f8e581e90f1bbb075a780ecf3c37a4fc4aa
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for WTForms ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/36/35/f3/7452cd24daeeaa5ec5b2ea13755316abc94e4e7702de29ba94
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for tornado ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/61/a8/89/044b56fd7bb4d2d6fd3ff45cc5c98b7b3bb68fed70617ffe13
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scandir ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/3d/51/95/79b749f7e52b5dea9e01b5c72da1c728151fc65a3984c37bec
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for sasl ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/03/97/72/71e18efd8929d907aaf6b33a43b5c463399bee8f59dc530ec2
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pycparser ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/95/14/9a/5e7b9024459d2a6600aaa64e0ba485325aff7a9ac7489db1b6
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MarkupSafe ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/88/a7/30/e39a54a87bcbe25308fa3ca64e8ddc75d9b3e5afa21ee32d57
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for python-openid ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/0a/da/67/e9e68f4b5e03732dc17a545b4ce3ce84b4a9bef67253d4ff72
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Mako ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/33/bf/8f/036f36c35e0e3c63a4685e306bce6b00b6349fec5b0947586e
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for python-editor ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/84/d6/b8/082dc3b5cd7763f17f5500a193b6b248102217cbaa3f0a24ca
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for backports.ssl-match-hostname ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/max/.cache/pip/wheels/5d/72/36/b2a31507b613967b728edc33378a5ff2ada0f62855b93c5ae1
Successfully built superset cryptography flask-appbuilder flask-cache flask-migrate flask-script flask-sqlalchemy flask-testing flower future humanize markdown PyHive pyyaml simplejson sqlalchemy sqlalchemy-utils thrift thrift-sasl billiard ipaddress itsdangerous Flask-Babel Flask-Login Flask-OpenID alembic WTForms tornado scandir sasl pycparser MarkupSafe python-openid Mako python-editor backports.ssl-match-hostname
Installing collected packages: jmespath, docutils, six, python-dateutil, botocore, futures, s3transfer, boto3, vine, amqp, kombu, pytz, billiard, celery, colorama, idna, asn1crypto, enum34, ipaddress, pycparser, cffi, cryptography, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, Werkzeug, click, itsdangerous, flask, babel, Flask-Babel, Flask-Login, python-openid, Flask-OpenID, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, WTForms, flask-wtf, flask-appbuilder, flask-cache, Mako, python-editor, alembic, flask-script, flask-migrate, flask-testing, backports.ssl-match-hostname, certifi, tornado, flower, future, humanize, gunicorn, markdown, numpy, pandas, parsedatetime, scandir, pathlib2, pydruid, PyHive, pyyaml, chardet, urllib3, requests, simplejson, sqlalchemy-utils, sqlparse, thrift, sasl, thrift-sasl, unidecode, superset
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/max/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/home/max/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jmespath'
max@ubuntu:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31512491

According to [pip install failing with: OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied on directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-failing-with-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied-on-directory), I tried this command line and it worked.

```
sudo pip install superset
```

Comment: Yes every time you see `Permission denied:` error on the last line on Linux systems you have to know that you need to run the previous command as **root**.