# Installing Python Pip on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, pip

Error Installing Python **Pip** on Mac OSX:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install -r: OSError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have write permission on the folders.

Try `sudo pip install twilio`