# Python3: Trying to upgrade pip3 in Ubuntu 16.04 but it doesn't update

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, terminal, pip

Basically, the title. I want to upgrade pip because I cannot get new packages in python because it is obsolete.

When I try to run `pip3 install --upgrade pip` from the Ubuntu terminal, this happens:

```
    Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-9.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 9.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-9.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-9.0.1
  Rolling back uninstall of pip
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marcell/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/marcell/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/marcell/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/home/marcell/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/home/marcell/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/home/marcell/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/home/marcell/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/home/marcell/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip'
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 9.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

How should I solve this problem? I tried to purge pip and reinstall it,but to no avail.

Edit: Also, tried the upgrade command with pip too, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: you need to run it as `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip`.

Comment: Any time you have permission denied, it usually means you need to add `sudo` to the start of your command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install -r: OSError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied)

Answer (score 4):

I have two solutions to your problem

1. Try using sudo as stated in above answer.

   sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
2. Try to do fresh reinstall of pip

   apt-get remove python3-pip

   pip3 install -U pip

NOTE: This can be done for python2x ,by replace pip3 by pip2

Answer (score 3):

- Try:

  ```
  sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
  ```

"Permission denied" errors are usually solved by adding "sudo" to your commands.

(sudo is just a keyword to execute a given command with privileges)

- If you get a "command not found" then you should do the following:

Type Python into your command console, it will tell you which version of Python you are using.

```
C:/>python
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

If you have **Python 3.x** you should use **pip3**, if you have **Python 2.x** you should use **pip**.

If you are using the right pip but still get the "command not found" then you have to install pip:

For **Python2.x**:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

For **Python 3.x**:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Comment: I tried that too, but for some reason it doesn't find pip3:
sudo: pip3: command not found

Comment: simply try pip, pip3 is used the OP might have both python2x and python3x . So, to just upgrade the pip of python3 pip3 is used

Comment: I edited the answer to answer you @marcell-fekete. Hope it helps pal!