# install scrapy with python 2.7 in OSX

Tags: macos, python-2.7, scrapy, pip

When i tried to install scrapy i got the following errors.
following are the output in my terminal, please any suggestions?
python is 2.7 and pip is 9.0.3 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

## pip install Scrapy

output in terminal (only the last exception part)

```
      Installing collected packages: six, w3lib, cssselect, lxml, parsel, queuelib, PyDispatcher, attrs, pyasn1, pyasn1-modules, service-identity, hyperlink, constantly, incremental, Automat, Twisted, Scrapy
        Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
          DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
          Uninstalling six-1.4.1:
      Exception:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
          status = self.run(options, args)
        File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
          prefix=options.prefix_path,
        File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
          requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
        File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
          paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
        File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
          renames(path, new_path)
        File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
          shutil.move(old, new)
        File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
          copy2(src, real_dst)
        File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
          copystat(src, dst)
        File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
          os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
      OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/vy/rptkx52n4w7dswc7svd1pwh40000gn/T/pip-Go6uIL-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install -r: OSError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied)