# Permission denied error by installing matplotlib

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, pip, failed-installation

I installed **opencv** with all dependencies. After the installation I tried to import **matplotlib** for a simple example.

Then I got the following error, when I tried to install matplotlib via pip with `pip install matplotlib`:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kiwisolver.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

What can I do to install matplotlib?

Comment: Consider using the `--user` option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install -r: OSError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

It looks like your user does not have the permission to install packages in your system (for all users). Here's how to fix this problem for Linux, macOS and Windows.

---

## Linux / macOS

From your terminal, you can **install the package for your user only**, like this:

```
pip install <package> --user
```

***OR***

You can use `su` or `sudo` from your terminal, to **install the package as `root`**:

```
sudo pip install <package>
```

---

## Windows

From the Command Prompt, you can **install the package for your user only**, like this:

```
pip install <package> --user
```

***OR***

You can **install the package as Administrator**, by following these steps:

1. Right click on the Command Prompt icon
2. Select the option `Run This Program As An Administrator`
3. Run the command `pip install <package>`

Comment: Running the command line as an administrator produced the same error. Using the --user option (still running as an administrator) worked.

Comment: It worked. I tried as follows.
pip install psycopg2-binary --user

Comment: Try --user before going the sudo route

Comment: this works in linux: sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib

Answer (score 17):

I solved this issue by typing the following command,

```
pip install --user <package_name>
```

Example,

```
pip install --user tensorflow
```

NOTE: You should not enter your own username for this command. Please enter with '--user'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo pip install matplotlib
```

Comment: Please try not to post code/command only. An explanation of "why this works" will make your answer more acceptable.

Comment: This installs it globally yet I want it installed in my virtualenv

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the permission to install a package globally, so you can use `sudo pip install matplotlib`, but it isn't recommended.

The recommended way is using [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) or [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/) to create a virtual environment.

venv:

1. Create a python virtual environment, command: `python3 -m venv <DIR>`
2. Activate the virtual environment, command: `source <DIR>/bin/activate`
3. Install matplotlib, command: `pip install matplotlib`