# Installing yfinance errors window 7 Anaconda

Tags: python, numpy, pip, yfinance

I tried installing yfinance using `pip install yfinance` and I got:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'd:\\users\\myself\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\multiarray.cp36-win_amd64.pyd'
Consider using the '--user' option or check the permissions.
```

Then tried `conda install -c ranaroussi yfinance` and got:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - scipy
  - yfinance -> numpy >=1.15 -> blas 1.1 openblas
  - yfinance -> numpy >=1.15 -> mkl >=2019.4,<2020.0a0 1.1 openblas
  - yfinance -> numpy >=1.15 -> mkl-service >=2,<3.0a0
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Any idea what's going on and how I can install it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Case 1: `pip`**

Source: [Permission denied error by installing matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087098/permission-denied-error-by-installing-matplotlib)

## Linux / macOS

From your terminal, you can **install the package for your user only**, like this:

```
pip install <package> --user
```

***OR***

You can use `su` or `sudo` from your terminal, to **install the package as `root`**:

```
sudo pip install <package>
```

---

## Windows

From the Command Prompt, you can **install the package for your user only**, like this:

```
pip install <package> --user
```

***OR***

You can **install the package as Administrator**, by following these steps:

1. Right click on the Command Prompt icon
2. Select the option `Run This Program As An Administrator`
3. Run the command `pip install <package>`

P/s: You don't have the right/permission, hence the system block you from installing via pip, you need to be an administrator.

**Case 2: `conda`**

This message tells you that the library/package version required by finance has a conflict with the existing preinstalled one. One solution will be create another environment for it.

Source: [Anaconda - UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589141/anaconda-unsatisfiableerror-the-following-specifications-were-found-to-be-in)

Create a new conda environment for Python 3:

```
conda create -n your_virtual_env python=3.7
```

Create a new conda environment for Python 2.7:

```
conda create -n your_virtual_env python=2.7
```

Activate it:

```
conda activate your_virtual_env
```

Alternatively, for older conda versions on Windows:

```
activate your_virtual_env
```

on Unix (including Mac OS X):

```
source activate your_virtual_env
```

Once activated, install your packages:

```
conda install yfinance
```

Comment: Thank you! I used pip install yfinance --user as you suggested and it solved the problem but now something bigger happened. 
I had the following two lines: 
"from pandas_datareader import data" AND
"import pandas_datareader.data as web"
and for both of them, I'm getting "ImportError: cannot import name 'urlencode'". I think one of the updates I made ruined everything as this was working fine before yfinance installation.

Comment: Uninstalled pandas_datareader and reinstalled it and all is working fine. Thanks.