# upgrading packages in python

Tags: python, pip, upgrade

I'm looking to update Python packages. But by running this code

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

in Command Prompt, I get the following error

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\pip\\_internal\\build_env.py'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: use a terminal with administrator privilege

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087098/permission-denied-error-by-installing-matplotlib

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ERROR%3A+Could+not+install+packages+due+to+an+EnvironmentError%3A+WinError+5+Access+is+denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have permissions. Either add a flag `--user` to your command or open a terminal as an administrator.