# Exception when upgrading pip to 10.0.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, pip, macos-high-sierra

When installing new modules via pip3, it will install the module, then throw an [IO Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYN35.png) exception, then it tells me to upgrade to the new pip version, 10.0.1 - which I have. When I `pip install --upgrade pip`, an [OS Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2f4l.png) is raised. After searching the web, I found that with El Capitan, an exception was raised although it deals with Six module in pip. After experimenting with that idea, I did `pip install --ignore-installed six`, and an [IO Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lp16f.png) occurred.

Questions:

> I'd like help in understanding why the exceptions are being raised and hopefully how to solve the issue.
>
> Figure out why the exceptions are targeting python2.7 and not python3 version.
>
> Why pip is ignoring the already upgraded pip3 version 10.0.1.
>
> Lastly, having both pip and pip3, does one need to make regular upgrades or module installations on both - or do they communicate with each other in this retrospect?

Version & Path:

```
OS: High Sierra 10.13.4
which python: usr/bin/python
python --version: 2.7.10
which python3: usr/local/bin/python3
python3 --version: 3.6.5
which pip: usr/local/bin/pip
pip --version: 9.0.1
which pip3: usr/local/bin/pip3
pip3 --version: 10.0.1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install -r: OSError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied)

Comment: @phd it doesn't seem to be the exact issue, although when i create a virtualenv (as one of the solutions to the link), the errors go away and so does the `upgrade pip` problem.

Comment: Did you tried it with `sudo`?