# pip said permission denied when I use it

Tags: permissions, pip

I get this message whenever I install using pip

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Markdown-2.6.11.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I also get these kind of message said this is not capatable.

```
requests 2.18.4 has requirement idna<2.7,>=2.5, but you'll have idna 2.7 which is incompatible.
requests 2.18.4 has requirement urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1, but you'll have urllib3 1.23 which is incompatible.
```

Why does it happen? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install -r: OSError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied)

Answer (score 0):

`pip`, by default, tries to install system-wide modules in a location that usually only `root` has permissions to write to.

As the error message suggests, you could use the `--user` option to install modules under your user:

```
$ pip install --user requests
```