# When I was downloaded “Pip”, I got an error

Tags: linux, pip, object-detection

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkbwK.png)I am working object detection project. Firstly, i need to downloading “pip” and I did it. But i got an error(like in photo), and I haven’t any idea. How can i solve, do you have any idea?

Comment: Please add the error as text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install -r: OSError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prefix your commands with `sudo` because they are meant to be run as root.

Example: `sudo apt-get update`.

Be careful when using sudo, you can really mess up a system as root.