# Environment error when installing with pip

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pip

I'm trying to install some python libraries with `pip` and I'm getting a repeated error when running it. For example, if I run `pip install -U py2app` the download appears to proceed as normally, but then an error is raised:

`Could not install packages due to an EnviromentError`

Which is followed by a series of `[Errno 1] Operation not permitted` errors  (with directories listed after each error).

This error has appeared a number of times on several different libraries I've attempted to install, and it's extremely frustrating. I've tried to update the tools that people have recommended to update for various pip errors and none of them have made any difference.

Is there an easy fix to this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install -r: OSError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+OSError+permission+denied

Answer (score 0):

Try to install using the option `--user` for example:

```
$ pip install --user py2app
```

Passing the `--user` option will install a package just for the current user, rather than for all users of the system.