# Install robot framework with python in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, testing, pip, robotframework

I have tried installing Robot Framework with python 2.7 in Ubuntu 16.04.
firstly I installed Python and then I installed pip after that I installed  Robot Framework

> pip install robot framework

and then selenium library

> `pip install robotframework-selenium2library`

with pip.

After that when I tried to install RIDE IDE using pip

> pip install robotframework-ride

I am unable to install RIDE and I am getting an error like

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/robotframework_ride-1.5.2.1.dist-info'
>   Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

I tried with the permission thing but I am still unable to solve the issue.

I googled the solution but couldn't find an exact solution to this issue.

Comment: Try install with sudo

Comment: are you aware that you don't need RIDE in order to use robotframework? You can use any plain text editor, and many popular ones come with robotframework plugins.

Comment: So what happens when you use `--user` option?

Comment: You DID install Robot Framework. It's RIDE what you cannot install.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install -r: OSError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied)

Comment: Thank You guys I learned to use it using a normal text editor.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching the answer for this took me a lot of time especially in the case of wxpython installation. With these steps, you can install and setup the Robot Framework in your Linux machine.

## Installing Robot Framework with RIDE on ubuntu.

### Preconditions: Python

### Install Python

`➜  ~ sudo apt install python2.7`

### Install python pip

`➜  ~ sudo apt install python-pip`

### wxPython

```
➜  ~ echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wily-copies.list

➜  ~ sudo apt update

➜  ~ sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8
```

### Robot Framework + Selenium2Library

`➜  ~ sudo pip install robotframework-selenium2library`

### RIDE (Robot IDE)

```
➜  ~ sudo  pip install robotframework-ride

➜  ~ ride.py
```

Answer (score 4):

You will need permission to install . Just try with `sudo`.

```
sudo pip install robotframework-ride
```

Comment: Ride IDE did not work for me so I learned to use with normal text editor and pybot.

Comment: @Alesh Why you can't use ? could u tell me the erorr ?

Comment: Now I have installed it and running fine on my Linux machine. @Sidera KEO