# Pip not installing packages without --user on my own laptop

Tags: python, macos, pip

Recently I messed up my steady environment by installing multiple versions of python.

What I'm trying to do: install a particular package using pip

pip cannot install any package without the --user tag

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13 Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL
```

Here's More information:

```
which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

which python
/usr/bin/python
```

What should I do?

Comment: Just use virtualenvs, much easier and safer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install -r: OSError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied)

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo` or `su` to install packages system-wide.

Comment: Apparently it's not recommended: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied

Comment: but needed sometimes. for example for hand-made daemons.

Comment: But only sometimes. For the general use case, use `virtualenv` or `--user`.

Comment: I using `--user`. Just another way is setting `PYTHONPATH`.