# Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Pip install Pytest

Tags: macos, terminal, pip, pytest

I am having issues when trying to set up pytest. When I run:

```
pip install pytest pytest-cache
```

I receive this error message:

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/apipkg'
>   Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install -r: OSError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Could+not+install+packages+due+to+an+EnvironmentError%3A+Errno+13+Permission+denied

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message you do not have permission to install in the Library directory & you can use `--user` option to install it.

```
pip install pytest pytest-cache --user
```

---

```
$ pip install --help

--user    Install to the Python user install directory for your platform. Typically ~/.local/, or %APPDATA%\Python on Windows. (See the Python documentation for site.USER_BASE for
                              full details.)
```

Or if you have sudo access, you can use `sudo` to install in the Library directory

```
sudo pip install pytest pytest-cache.
```

An alternative & recommended approach is to use [virtualenv](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/)