# How to fix an EnvironmentError occuring in a virtual env while installing tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow in a virtual env using "pip3 install tensorflow" on ubuntu 16.04. I am getting an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13].

I was getting few more EnvironmentErrors when I was trying it without using virtual env. I found that using a virtual env would solve it. But it's not happening. Perhaps this is a python version problem. I am not sure

Installing collected packages: grpcio, absl-py, tensorboard, backports.weakref, termcolor, funcsigs, mock, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/tensorboard'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

I expect the tensorflow to be installed. But i am getting this error. Please help.

Comment: Have you already read other discussions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied) ?

Comment: Yes I did. I created the virtual environment and installed it successfully. But when I import tensorflow, I get 

 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/signal.py", line 4, in <module>
    from enum import IntEnum as _IntEnum
ImportError: cannot import name 'IntEnum'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow'

I looked for solutions for this error. None of them are working.