# Bad interpreter: Permission denied when using pip to install boto3

Tags: python, pip

When running

```sh
pip install boto3
```

I get

```sh
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

I think it has something to do with `pip` trying to look for a python installation under `/usr/bin/python`, but a symlink to `/usr/bin/python` isn't created for me? I may have deleted that symlink when I upgraded from python 2.7.6 to python 2.7.9.

In my `~/.bashrc` I have `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7.9/bin`.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Comment: It doesn't say that `/usr/bin/python` is missing, it says that the permissions are wrong. Fix the permissions.

Comment: It's not using `$PATH`, it has an explicit `#!/usr/bin/python` in the script.

Comment: usualy on Linux you need to use `sudo` to install Python module in global folder. Without `sudo` you can only install in user's folder using option `--user`

Comment: Please post the result of `ls -l /usr/bin/python`.

Comment: @furas Yeah, that would give a different error though: [`OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: ...`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31512422/4518341). Also BTW `sudo pip install` should be avoided; `pip install --user` is the better option.

Comment: `ls -l /usr/bin/python` gives me `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Jul  5 20:29 /usr/bin/python -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7.9`

Comment: @Barmar what permissions should I fix?

Comment: The link should point to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7.9/bin/python`.