# pip install uvloop causes permission denied error

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip, uvloop

I try to install `uvloop` into a Python 3.9 venv on CentOS 7. These are **all** actions I take:

```
cd ~
mkdir python_envs
cd python_envs
python -m venv test
source test/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install uvloop
```

Then I get this:

```
Collecting uvloop
  Using cached uvloop-0.14.0.tar.gz (2.0 MB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for uvloop, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: uvloop
    Running setup.py install for uvloop ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/music/python_envs/test/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-85ij25up/uvloop_2c4ab2d368cc414bb626701bc788f90f/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-85ij25up/uvloop_2c4ab2d368cc414bb626701bc788f90f/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-l3ksyogz/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/music/python_envs/test/include/site/python3.9/uvloop
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-85ij25up/uvloop_2c4ab2d368cc414bb626701bc788f90f/
    Complete output (76 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop
    copying uvloop/_noop.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop
    copying uvloop/_patch.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop
    copying uvloop/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop
    copying uvloop/_testbase.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop
    running egg_info
    writing uvloop.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to uvloop.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to uvloop.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'uvloop.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vendor/libuv/.git'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vendor/libuv/docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vendor/libuv/img'
    writing manifest file 'uvloop.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    copying uvloop/cbhandles.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop
    copying uvloop/cbhandles.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop
    copying uvloop/dns.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop
    copying uvloop/errors.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop
    copying uvloop/loop.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop
    copying uvloop/loop.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop
    copying uvloop/loop.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop
    copying uvloop/lru.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop
    copying uvloop/pseudosock.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop
    copying uvloop/request.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop
    copying uvloop/request.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop
    copying uvloop/server.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop
    copying uvloop/server.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop
    copying uvloop/sslproto.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop
    copying uvloop/sslproto.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/async_.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/async_.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/basetransport.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/basetransport.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/check.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/check.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/handle.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/handle.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/idle.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/idle.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/pipe.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/pipe.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/poll.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/poll.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/process.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/process.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/stream.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/stream.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/streamserver.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/streamserver.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/tcp.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/tcp.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/timer.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/timer.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/udp.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    copying uvloop/handles/udp.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/handles
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/includes
    copying uvloop/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/includes
    copying uvloop/includes/compat.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/includes
    copying uvloop/includes/consts.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/includes
    copying uvloop/includes/debug.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/includes
    copying uvloop/includes/debug.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/includes
    copying uvloop/includes/flowcontrol.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/includes
    copying uvloop/includes/fork_handler.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/includes
    copying uvloop/includes/python.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/includes
    copying uvloop/includes/stdlib.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/includes
    copying uvloop/includes/system.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/includes
    copying uvloop/includes/uv.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/uvloop/includes
    running build_ext
    error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './configure'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/music/python_envs/test/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-85ij25up/uvloop_2c4ab2d368cc414bb626701bc788f90f/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-85ij25up/uvloop_2c4ab2d368cc414bb626701bc788f90f/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-l3ksyogz/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/music/python_envs/test/include/site/python3.9/uvloop Check the logs for full command output.
```

I think the key error message is `error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './configure'`, but I don't know which directory this occurs.
I have already read this answer and some related info but it seems not to solve my problem:
[pip install failing with: OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied on directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-failing-with-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied-on-directory)

1. `install in env`: as you see, I do this in a brand new env but not work.
2. `pip install --user`: not work, I get this:

```
ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.
```

3. `pip install --user` + modify `include-system-site-packages = false` to `true` in `pyvenv.cfg` of the env: installation can be started, but back to original permission denied problem.
4. `sudo`: not safe and will cause other problems. I will keep this as the last solution.
5. `chmod -R 777 test`: this is not a solution, just a test for making sure the problem is not on the permissions of env directories. The same permission problem still occurs.
   I know there are some different install methods can avoid this permission problem, but I want to know the reason, and is there a way to make `pip install -r requirement.txt` work well without handling this special case?

### Update:

Even I do

```
sudo -s        # become root
source test/bin/activate
pip install uvloop
```

and still the same problem `error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './configure'` is happened.
I have no idea how could this happed.

Comment: `chmod +x /tmp` then trying again?

Comment: @CristiFati Thanks for the comment. However, ```\tmp``` had already been ```drwxrwxrwt.  37 root root 12288 Dec 23 01:59 tmp``` (which is the default) before the installation. Therefore, ```chmod +x /tmp``` do not solve the problem.

Comment: Hmmm, what about `pip install --prefer-binary uvloop`?

Comment: @CristiFati I found that is a version problem, so I think forcing installation on Python 3.9 may be not a good choice. My choice is back to Python 3.8 and waiting for the Python 3.9 version of uvloop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download [uvloop wheel](https://pypi.org/project/uvloop/0.14.0/#files) from here.

Then use `pip install uvloop-XXX.whl`

But I found that there is no version corresponding to python3.9.

Comment: Maybe that's the point! I try to create another venv by Python 3.8 and the pip installation works. Seems the version problem...