# I can't install Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pip, python-requests, pyinstaller, python-3.9

When i try to do "pip install pyinstaller" I get this error (Python 39)

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\kaito\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-x1uajlp_\\pefile\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\kaito\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-x1uajlp_\\pefile\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\kaito\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-i794i3gc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python39\Include\pefile'
         cwd: C:\Users\kaito\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-x1uajlp_\pefile\
    Complete output (14 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib
    copying pefile.py -> build\lib
    copying peutils.py -> build\lib
    creating build\lib\ordlookup
    copying ordlookup\oleaut32.py -> build\lib\ordlookup
    copying ordlookup\ws2_32.py -> build\lib\ordlookup
    copying ordlookup\__init__.py -> build\lib\ordlookup
    running install_lib
    byte-compiling c:\python39\Lib\site-packages\pefile.py to pefile.cpython-39.pyc
    error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\python39\\Lib\\site-packages\\__pycache__\\pefile.cpython-39.pyc.2747580017328'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\kaito\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-x1uajlp_\\pefile\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\kaito\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-x1uajlp_\\pefile\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\kaito\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-i794i3gc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python39\Include\pefile' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I can't seem to fix this issue, please help!

Answer (score 1):

Well, error is clear, you don't have access to the folder that you are trying to install the pip package.

Use the command `pip install --user pyinstaller`

If that doesn't do the job:

Create a virtualenv and install the package in there:

1. Open up a terminal.
2. Go to your project folder using the command `cd`
3. Create a virtual environment with the command `virtualenv venv`
4. Activate the virtual environment with the command `\venv\Scripts\activate.bat`
5. After activating the virtual environment, you have a virtual environment that you have permissions to create/edit/delete files. So, you can install the package in there with the command `pip install pyinstaller`

You may also want to check the file permissions by right clicking the folder in the path below.

> c:\python39\Lib\site-packages\

Also there is a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-failing-with-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied-on-directory) that you might want to check. It could give you an idea about what is wrong.

Comment: Can you add the error you get in here so I can understand what is wrong? Maybe you haven't installed virtualenv package yet? Have you tried to install the pyinstaller with the command pip install --user pyinstaller?

Comment: After I did the command, I still can't use pyinstaller as a command.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is:

```
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

This is probably because you are not an admin user on your computer.
You can either switch to an admin account or run terminal/command prompt as an admin
(right click on command prompt select "run as admin")

Answer (score 0):

Run cmd as Administrator. Select Yes in UAC window.