# mac os pip3 install permision error. Check the permissions

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/user/Library/Python/3.8/lib'
Check the permissions.
```

I use **pip3 install --user --upgrade tensorflow**.

Why Is't work... Somebody help me pls..

Comment: Seems it gives an error because you don't have a permission

Comment: pip does not recommend using sudo. There are many comments telling you to put --user when you don't have permission.

Comment: The error occurred due to an issue with mac m1. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip install failing with: OSError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied on directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-failing-with-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied-on-directory)

Answer (score 0):

I probably meet the same problem.

```
pip3 install lxml
```

Result:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-4.6.3-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (4.6 MB)
Installing collected packages: lxml
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/username/Library/Python/3.8'
Check the permissions.
```

Mostly of answers tell us to add --user

```
pip3 install lxml --user
```

Result:

```
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-4.6.3-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (4.6 MB)
Installing collected packages: lxml
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/username/Library/Python/3.8'
Check the permissions.
```

I don't want to use **sudo** to install package

```
sudo pip3 install lxml
```

I can't **install** then use **virtualenv**

```
virtualenv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I found only **Python** on path '/Users/username/Library/' be owned by root,

```
...
drwxr-xr-x    5 username  staff    160  6 29  2015 PubSub
drwx------    3 root      staff     96  3  6  2019 Python
drwxr-xr-x@   4 username  staff    128 10 21  2020 Reminders
drwxr-xr-x   37 username  staff   1184  8 19 23:03 Safari
drwxr-xr-x@   2 username  staff     64  3 12  2018 SafariSafeBrowsing
...
```

I decided to use **chown**, problem solved.

```
sudo chown -R $USER  /Users/username/Library/Python
```

I had no idea what time dose Python folder be owned by root.