# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [13] Permission denied: '/nix/store/8d3695w7vasap3kkcn3yk731v4iw2kcv-python3.8-pip-21.1.3/bin/pip

Tags: python, pip, nix, replit

I've been working on one error for about an hour. I've been development an app in Nix on REPLIT. But no matter what I do this error comes while installing packages with with Python Pip:

Firstly, this came up whilst installing any packages... But I realized it also comes up in attempt to update Pip.

`` ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/nix/store/8d3695w7vasap3kkcn3yk731v4iw2kcv-python3.8-pip-21.1.3/bin/pip' Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions. ``

[i1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Opaxp.png)

My replit.nix:

```
{ pkgs }: {
    deps = [
        pkgs.cowsay
        pkgs.python38Full
        pkgs.python38Packages.pip
    ];
    env = {
      PYTHONBIN = "${pkgs.python38Full}/bin/python3.8";
      LANG = "en_US.UTF-8";
    };
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip install failing with: OSError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied on directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-failing-with-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied-on-directory)

Comment: What happens if you use `--user` as suggested? `/nix/store/*` being readonly is to be expected, that is a feature of `nix`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the --user option installs the package in the user's home directory.

Eg.

```
pip install octosuite --user
```