# Unable to uninstall setuptools to reinstall it

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi4, adafruit-circuitpython

I’m trying to set up my Raspberry Pi, and `blinka` is not installing, and I have been backtracking to reinstall my `setuptools` since I have the error where the board is not importing. And I am receiving an error:

> 13 permission denied ‘/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/_distutils_hack/‘

Please I am losing my mind.

I have tried deleting the files to see if I can get a fresh restart and it then denies permission from that same file.

Comment: what is the command you're executing?

Comment: Are you working with the system interpreter or some virtual environment? Be careful messing with the system interpreter - there be dragons.

Comment: pip uninstall setuptools, pip install --upgrade setuptools --user python,

Comment: do you mean `pip install --upgrade setuptools --user` instead? why the extra `python`?

Comment: I just tried basically anything i could find online regarding board errors, and the permission and restart the process multiple times. There was no particular reason for the extra python besides losing track of what i had and hadnt tried at that point. I’m more used to working with arduinos than i am with raspberry pi.

Comment: So please tell us what happens if you follow Raptors advice? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/42021993/18667225 and the comments below.

Comment: Error: exception: traceback (most recent call last): File “/usr/share/python-wheels/resolvelib-0.5.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/resolvelib/resolvers.py”, line 171, in _merge_into_criterion if i try to pip install —user adafruit-blinka

Comment: If i try pip install —user setuptools i get Requirement already satisfied

Comment: I tried to sudo pip3 insttall rpi_ws281x adafruit-circuitpython-neopixel however i get an error while its collecting pyusb!=1.2.0,>=1.0.0 Downloading https://www.piwheels.org/simply/pyusb/pyusb-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl with the same error as the traceback

Answer (score 1):

I ended up factory restarting the raspberry pi cause I was worried I had corrupted something at some point, and it is working fine now.