# Pip permission denied due to inaccessible package

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pip, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use pip (specifically pip3) to install a library for Python 3.6 and I am running into some difficulties. The install process fails due to a "Permission Denied" error caused by the chromedriver_autoinstaller package. I am trying this on CENTOS7 and I am executing all commands as root

When I try to install this library I get the following output:

```
# pip3 install natsort
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 16, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 11, in main
    from pip._internal.utils.entrypoints import _wrapper
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/entrypoints.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/configuration.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._internal.exceptions import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/exceptions.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.pkg_resources import Distribution
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3251, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3235, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3264, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 574, in _build_master
    ws = cls()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 567, in __init__
    self.add_entry(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 623, in add_entry
    for dist in find_distributions(entry, True):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2065, in find_on_path
    for dist in factory(fullpath):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2127, in distributions_from_metadata
    if len(os.listdir(path)) == 0:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chromedriver_autoinstaller-0.6.2.dist-info'
```

Looking at the site-packages folder I noticed the perms for that specific folder were as follows:

`drwx------.  2 root root   4096 Nov 16 15:47 chromedriver_autoinstaller-0.6.2.dist-info`

Anything I do to try and change the permissions for this folder are met with "Permission denied". How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it is not a good idea to run `pip install` with sudo or root privileges because of security concerns.
There are two better options:
Install for only your user with `pip install --user <package_name>` or (**preferrably**) create a venv or conda environment. This will allow you to install anything in isolation of the rest of your system.

You can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-failing-with-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied-on-directory) for more elaborate answers.